# Unable to start MSSQL and SQLSERVERAGENT in Windows Server 2003

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

We are using `MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2000` Enterprise Edition. Our main problem we cant start `MSSQL and SQLSERVERAGENT services`.

Heres the Error log :

```
=====================================================================          
       BugCheck Dump                                                           
=====================================================================          

This file is generated by Microsoft SQL Server 8.00.2039                       
upon detection of fatal unexpected error. Please return this file,             
the query or program that produced the bugcheck, the database and              
the error log, and any other pertinent information with a Service Request.     

Computer type is AT/AT COMPATIBLE.                                             
Bios Version is ASUS   - 42302e31                                              
Award Modular BIOS v6.0                                                        
Current time is 09:23:51 10/04/12.                                             
2 Intel x86 level 15, 3000 Mhz processor(s).                                   
Windows NT 5.2 Build 3790 CSD .                                                


Memory                    
MemoryLoad = 35%          
Total Physical = 511 MB    
Available Physical = 328 MB                         
Total Page File = 1250 MB  
Available Page File = 1002 MB                       
Total Virtual = 2047 MB    
Available Virtual = 2012 MB                         

*Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\log\SQLDu
mp1515.txt                                                                     
* *****************************************************************************
**                                                                             
*                                                                              
* BEGIN STACK DUMP:                                                            
*   10/04/12 09:23:51 spid 0                                                   
*                                                                              
*   Exception Address = 77E6C061 (OpenFile + 00000022 Line 0+00000000)         
*   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION                    
*   Access Violation occurred reading address 00000001                         
*                                                                              
*  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE                    
* sqlservr                       00400000  00CBBFFF  008bc000                  
* ntdll                          77F40000  77FF9FFF  000ba000                  
* kernel32                       77E40000  77F33FFF  000f4000                  
* ADVAPI32                       77DA0000  77E2FFFF  00090000                  
* RPCRT4                         77C50000  77CF3FFF  000a4000                  
* MSVCP71                        7C3A0000  7C41AFFF  0007b000                  
* MSVCR71                        7C340000  7C395FFF  00056000                  
* opends60                       41060000  41065FFF  00006000                  
* SHELL32                        77380000  77B5CFFF  007dd000                  
* msvcrt                         77BA0000  77BF3FFF  00054000                  
* GDI32                          77C00000  77C43FFF  00044000                  
* USER32                         77D00000  77D8EFFF  0008f000                  
* SHLWAPI                        77290000  772D8FFF  00049000                  
* sqlsort                        42AE0000  42B6FFFF  00090000                  
* ums                            41070000  4107DFFF  0000e000                  
* comctl32                       70AD0000  70BB5FFF  000e6000                  
* waa1                           00E50000  00EC2FFF  00073000                  
* COMCTL32                       70BC0000  70C4FFFF  00090000                  
* MPR                            71BD0000  71BE0FFF  00011000                  
* OLE32                          77160000  77283FFF  00124000                  
* OLEAUT32                       770E0000  7715CFFF  0007d000                  
* WSOCK32                        71BB0000  71BB8FFF  00009000                  
* WS2_32                         71C00000  71C17FFF  00018000                  
* WS2HELP                        71BF0000  71BF7FFF  00008000                  
* sqlevn70                       41080000  4108AFFF  0000b000                  
* dbghelp                        02800000  028FFFFF  00100000                  
*                                                                              
*        Edi: 0108FCD4: 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000
000                                                                            
*        Esi: 00000001:                                                        
*        Eax: 00000000:                                                        
*        Ebx: 00000001:                                                        
*        Ecx: 00000022:                                                        
*        Edx: 00EAA5AC: 000C7638  FFFFFFFF  00000000  00000000  00000000  00000
000                                                                            
*        Eip: 77E6C061: 4D83A5F3  4589FFE4  5DE850FC  8BFFFD59  C6F61055  5E850
F01                                                                            
*        Ebp: 0108FDDC: 0108FDFC  00E51F4E  00000006  00000001  0108FE18  00000
000                                                                            
*      SegCs: 0000001B:                                                        
*     EFlags: 00010246: 004F0047  0053004E  00520045  00450056  003D0052  005C0
05C                                                                            
*        Esp: 0108FCC8: 0108FE18  00000001  00000006  00000000  00000000  00000
000                                                                            
*      SegSs: 00000023:                                                        
* *****************************************************************************
**                                                                             
* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                                                             
* Short Stack Dump                                                             
* 77E6C061 Module(kernel32+0002C061) (OpenFile+00000022)                       
* 00E51F4E Module(waa1+00001F4E) (AttachHook+00000092)                         
* 005B0F7B Module(sqlservr+001B0F7B) (SQLExit+00049484)                        
* 00565578 Module(sqlservr+00165578)                                           
* 77DB571B Module(ADVAPI32+0001571B) (ControlService+000000A3)                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Location   : 77E6C061 Module(kernel32+0002C061) (OpenFile+00000022)          
* Return Addr: 00E51F4E Module(waa1+00001F4E) (AttachHook+00000092)            
Frame      : 0108FDDC                                                          
Parameters:                                                                    
  [1] 00000006:                                                                
  [2] 00000001:                                                                
  [3] 0108FE18: 364C5153  55525F30  4E494E4E  80580047  8051FA00  0000002C     
  [4] 00000000:                                                                
  160 bytes of stack data from 0108FD3C to 0108FDDC                            
0108FD3C:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  [................]             
0108FD4C:  BD68092E 0000000E E1AE171C EF8F4617  [..h..........F..]             
0108FD5C:  0000000C E1AE172C 80F50565 8058001A  [....,...e.....X.]             
0108FD6C:  E1AE173A D319FBA2 E1F6000E E1AE1756  [:...........V...]             
0108FD7C:  B74976C2 00000030 E1AE1766 C7C00B02  [.vI.0...f.......]             
0108FD8C:  E1F60010 E1AE1786 F1370C64 00000000  [........d.7.....]             
0108FD9C:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  [................]             
0108FDAC:  00000000 FFFFFFFF 00000000 0108FFDC  [................]             
0108FDBC:  00E99777 00EA4604 0108FCC8 0108F8F0  [w....F..........]             
0108FDCC:  0108FFDC 77E70ABC 77E83EE0 FFFFFFFF  [.......w.>.w....]             

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Location   : 00E51F4E Module(waa1+00001F4E) (AttachHook+00000092)            
* Return Addr: 005B0F7B Module(sqlservr+001B0F7B) (SQLExit+00049484)           
Frame      : 0108FDFC                                                          
Parameters:                                                                    
  [1] 00000006:                                                                
  [2] 00000001:                                                                
  [3] 0108FE18: 364C5153  55525F30  4E494E4E  80580047  8051FA00  0000002C     
  [4] 000C4178: 00000001  005654FF  000C4184  5153534D  5245534C  00524556     
  32 bytes of stack data from 0108FDDC to 0108FDFC                             
0108FDDC:  0108FDFC 00E51F4E 00000006 00000001  [....N...........]             
0108FDEC:  0108FE18 00000000 00E51F0C 00000001  [................]             

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Location   : 005B0F7B Module(sqlservr+001B0F7B) (SQLExit+00049484)           
* Return Addr: 00565578 Module(sqlservr+00165578)                              
Frame      : 0108FF24                                                          
Parameters:                                                                    
  [1] FFDFF900:                                                                
  [2] F1370BFC:                                                                
  [3] 00000000:                                                                
  [4] 80747A2F:                                                                
  296 bytes of stack data from 0108FDFC to 0108FF24                            
0108FDFC:  0108FF24 005B0F7B 00000006 00000001  [$...{.[.........]             
0108FE0C:  0108FE18 000C4178 000C4178 364C5153  [....xA..xA..SQL6]             
0108FE1C:  55525F30 4E494E4E 80580047 8051FA00  [0_RUNNING.X...Q.]             
0108FE2C:  0000002C 00000000 000AF7F8 00000000  [,...............]             
0108FE3C:  F1370AC0 00000000 F1370D3C 804E5A30  [..7.....<.7.0ZN.]             
0108FE4C:  8051FA08 FFFFFFFF 8051FA00 8059DEFF  [..Q.......Q...Y.]             
0108FE5C:  8058A247 F1370D64 000AF6C8 8058A190  [G.X.d.7.......X.]             
0108FE6C:  00000000 F1370B58 805885C5 00000000  [....X.7...X.....]             
0108FE7C:  00000000 F1370B5C 805889BD 00000003  [....\.7...X.....]             
0108FE8C:  F1370C01 00000000 81701E5C 822AB820  [..7.....\.p. .*.]             
0108FE9C:  81701E40 77F42E0B 77F433E7 77F42E0B  [@.p....w.3.w...w]             
0108FEAC:  77F433E7 77E640C5 FFFFFFFE 00000004  [.3.w.@.w........]             
0108FEBC:  0108FEE4 00000004 000C4178 00000103  [........xA......]             
0108FECC:  7FFDD000 00000374 000007EC 00000002  [....t...........]             
0108FEDC:  00000008 00000000 00000003 0108FF24  [............$...]             
0108FEEC:  005B2829 FFFFFFFE 00000003 00000000  [)([.............]             
0108FEFC:  00000F33 01020800 0000041D BFEBFBFF  [3...............]             
0108FF0C:  00000000 00000003 00000001 0108FEFC  [................]             
0108FF1C:  00000002 07C7EE93                    [........]                     

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Location   : 00565578 Module(sqlservr+00165578)                              
* Return Addr: 77DB571B Module(ADVAPI32+0001571B) (ControlService+000000A3)    
Frame      : 0108FFA8                                                          
Parameters:                                                                    
  [1] 00000001:                                                                
  [2] 000C4180: 000C4184  5153534D  5245534C  00524556  00520045  00450056     
  [3] 00000000:                                                                
  [4] 77E4A990: D4E0E850  90900000  33909090  6A5053ED  B8B9EB00  C000007B     
  132 bytes of stack data from 0108FF24 to 0108FFA8                            
0108FF24:  0108FFA8 00565578 FFDFF900 F1370BFC  [....xUV.......7.]             
0108FF34:  00000000 80747A2F 00000008 00000246  [..../zt.....F...]             
0108FF44:  804ED800 8175B260 8175B1C0 8175B350  [..N.`.u...u.P.u.]             
0108FF54:  00000001 8175B1C0 00000000 FFFFFFFF  [......u.........]             
0108FF64:  00000000 F1370C30 804EDA20 8175B1C0  [....0.7. .N...u.]             
0108FF74:  8175B320 80748090 E1595C04 E1595C04  [ .u...t..\Y..\Y.]             
0108FF84:  8059C4E0 7FFDD000 8175B1C0 00000000  [..Y.......u.....]             
0108FF94:  00000000 00000118 F1370C90 07C7EE93  [..........7.....]             
0108FFA4:  00000000                             [....]                         

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Location   : 77DB571B Module(ADVAPI32+0001571B) (ControlService+000000A3)    
* Return Addr: 00000000 Module(sqlservr+FFC00000)                              
Frame      : 0108FFEC                                                          
Parameters:                                                                    
  [1] 77DB570D: 24748B56  08468D08  FF36FF50  FF560456  DA100815  5EC03377     
  [2] 000C4178: 00000001  005654FF  000C4184  5153534D  5245534C  00524556     
  [3] 00000000:                                                                
  [4] 00000101:                                                                
* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                        

Session StackDump:
------------------
```

Here the log for the SQLAGENT.OUT

```
2012-10-03 15:34:45 - ? [094] SQLServerAgent started from command line
2012-10-03 15:34:45 - ! [359] The local host server is not running
2012-10-03 15:34:45 - ! [000] Unable to connect to server ''; SQLServerAgent cannot start
2012-10-03 15:34:45 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

We try to change the password on the Logon tab in the services but theres still no luck.

Comment: We recently change the password of the administrator account but I was able to change it in the services log on tab. Since then our server down.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2000 you should change the service account via the Enterprise Manager.

Right click on the server name and select "properties" then the security tab. Change the service account there.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this : 
run services.msc as an administrator.
In the services list, find SQLSERVERAGENT. If the startup type is not set to Automatic, right click on SQLSERVERAGENT and go to properties. Change startup type to Automatic , click Start and then Apply. You might also need to start the dependency services and then restart windows.